# Query with multiple LIKE and NOT IN condition

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I want to search the same value but in multiple fields. But escaping inscriptions for the last event. Is it possible?

I've tried the following, but without success.

```
SELECT id, login
FROM PERSON
WHERE login like '%toto%'
OR nickname like '%toto%'
OR name like '%toto%'
AND id NOT IN (
    SELECT p.id
    FROM PERSONNE p, INSCRIPTION i, EVENT e
    WHERE p.id = i.id_person 
    AND i.id_event = e.id
    AND i.id_event = (
        SELECT MAX(id) FROM EVENT))
GROUP BY login, nom, pseudo
```

Comment: Thanks you for this fast respond ! Work perfectly.

Wasnt so far away :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You just need to group the `OR` conditions.

```
SELECT id, login 
FROM   PERSON 
WHERE (login like '%toto%' OR nickname like '%toto%' OR name like '%toto%')
AND id NOT IN (SELECT p.id FROM PERSONNE p, INSCRIPTION i, EVENT e
               WHERE p.id = i.id_person 
               AND i.id_event = e.id
               AND i.id_event = (SELECT MAX(id) FROM EVENT))
GROUP BY login, nom, pseudo
```